# Putting an ADBannerView on top of a UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, iad

I'm trying to put an iAd banner in an app that is based on a UINavigationController (it's not the standard nav-base app proposed by xcode, cause I don't need the table view).
I'd like to place an ADBanner on its bottom, to be always visible, no matter how the user pops and pushes views.

I studied the iAdSuite example in the apple sample code, but, though it's reported among the "best practices", I don't think it's the best practice for what I need. It basically declares an ADBannerView in the app delegate class and then implements the ADBannerViewDelegate methods for every single view the app needs. That means implementing the ADBannerViewDelegate methods over and over again on every view controller class you need! It doesn't seem too smart... :(

I'd rather prefer to have an approach more similar to what Apple itself does in the tab bar based app, where you have a part of the window always occupied by the tab controller and all the views switching above without affecting the tab bar view below.
You can't directly put an ADBannerView along with the nav controller in the app delegate, because ADBanner needs to be placed in a view controller (you get a runtime error otherwise).

I tried to subclass from UIViewController, implementing the ADBannerViewDelegate in this class, and place it in the rootViewController along with a UINavigationController but I'm not having good luck with this approach...

Has anybody found a good, simple way to to this? Any hint?

Thank you for any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have just one class for `ADBannerViewDelegate`, and just one instance of `ADBanner` itself. When the currently active view changes, remove ADBanner from the old view, add it as a subview to the new view.

EDIT:

to clarify, you don't need each view implement the `ADBannerViewDelegate`. You only should have *one* class implement it (that class doesn't have to be a view controller for that matter).

You would also need to maintain a somewhere a property that would point to the currently active view (e.g. you can update that property in your Navigation Controller's `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:`, or come up with your own protocol for that if your views appear in a more complex way).

Then in your `ADBannerViewDelegate` you'd just resize the view currently pointed to by that current view property. The actual view doesn't even have to know it has an ad in it ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
What you suggests is exactly what the apple sample does.
And this makes perfect sense when you need to have different layout management policies for each of your views. Each view implements the delegate for the adbanner and the banner itself is added to the newest view and removed from the previous one.

Comment: But if you want to have exactly the same layout management for every view in your app (basically having your view shrinked a little bit to let the banner accommodate in the bottom or top of your window) why should you bother implementing the same methods for the banner delegate over and over again on every view controller?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to have your window host two subviews? One with a view controller that implements the banner delegate and lies on the bottom of your window, and the other occupying the rest of your window and managing navigation among views. 

This is what I'm trying to do... without success :(
Is it impossible?

Comment: no, you don't have to implement the ad delegate several times - I've added a clarification to the answer.